# Passing pointer to new object over nested calls

Tags: c++, pointers, nested, call, containers

The code is really simple, consisting of nested similar method calls on different classes, but the program keeps segfaulting on random occasions (always during the Add method though).

I call method Add on class CScreen instance to add an object CCircle, which is cloned (a new instance is created) and pointer is passed down hierarchically until it reaches xnode (my own implementation of list node).

```
int main (){
  CScreen S1;
  S1 . Add ( CCircle ( 3, 20, 20, 15 ) );
}

class CScreen {
  public:
    Qlist <Planimetric*> objects;

    void Add (const Planimetric & ob ) {
        objects.push_back( ob.clone() ); // returns pointer to new instance
        }
    ...

template<typename _Type>
class Qlist{
  public:
    Qnode <_Type> *start;

    Qlist() : start(null) {
        start = new Qnode<_Type>(-coordInfinity, -coordInfinity, coordInfinity, coordInfinity);
    }

    void push_back (const _Type & data) {
        start->push_back(data);
        }
    ...

template<typename _Type>
struct Qnode{
    xlist <_Type> objects;

    void push_back (const _Type & data) {
        objects.push_back(data);
        }
    ...

template<typename _Type>
class xlist{
  public:
    int sizeOfList;
    xnode<_Type> *first, *last;

    void push_back (const _Type & data) {
        sizeOfList ++;
        xnode<_Type> *nnp; // new node pointer ;)
        if(first == null)
            first = last = new xnode<_Type> (data);
         else
             last = last->next = nnp = new xnode<_Type>(data, last);
        }
    ...

template<typename _Type>
struct xnode{
    _Type data;
    xnode *prev, *next;
    xnode(const _Type & data, xnode* prev = null, xnode* next = null)
        : data(data), prev(prev), next(next) {}
    ...

class CCircle : public Planimetric {
  public:
    long long int x,y;
    long long int rsq;

    CCircle * clone () const {return new CCircle(*this);}

    CCircle (int ID, int x, int y, int r) : Planimetric(ID), x(x), y(y) { ...
            ...
    }
```

I thought it might be a stack overflow because of the high overhead, but it sometimes segfaults on first call. The xlist and xnode implementation worked perfectly until i implemented Qlist.

I'm passing down const pointer reference, which is then copied in constructor in xnode. Could the problem be there? I've tried to debug with gdb, with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried valgrind?

Comment: Is clone() declared virtual in Planimetric ? Otherwise this might cause slicing.

Comment: Yes, it is virtual: virtual Planimetric* clone() const = 0;

Comment: yes, I've tried valgrind, with no success